# Google App Engine and Android?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I want to create to applications one written for Google App Engine (strictly Java) and the other an Android app. I want the android app to connect to the GAE server. Via what API will I get support for JAX-WS?

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine from what I've seen promotes the usage of RESTful architectural style and thus is a JAX-RS reference implementation which is pretty straightforward (annotations on WebService methods, parameters etc.)

Plus, some of the packages you need in order to marshal-unmarshal request and responses are not included

If you so insist on using JAX-WS I would suggest you take a look at [this](http://www.redheap.com/2014/04/host-soap-web-service-on-google-app-engine.html) blog entry.

I would strongly advice you not to delve into a web service implementation with this approach, google app engine has already the endpoints API in order to deal with developers wanting just a backend to their apps.